# For a binomial distribution, where does this upper bound come from?

Tags: probability

Apparently, if I have a random variable $X$ with binomial distribution with $n$ items in total and $k$ items to pick, an upper bound for $P(X \ge k)$ is
$$
P(X \ge k) \le \binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k
$$
Plugging in values shows that this bound makes sense, but where does it come from? I'd prefer not to derive it from the complex CDF of the binomial.

Comment: I find hard to understand the part "$n$ items in total and $k$ elements to pick" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Building on @matiasmorant's comment, note that one of the parameters of a binomial distribution is the probability $p$ of "success" on each trial. You don't mention or even hint what $p$ might be here. Suppose $p=1$. Then $X$ is always $n$, and the bound above fails, since $P(X\ge k)=1$. So you need to answer what $p$ is. If you let $p\le \frac{1}{n}$, the bound you give is true. But without knowing more about $p$, it's not possible to answer this question.